# How to pass url with protocol as parameter in url of an api?

Tags: node.js, express

```js
app.get('/new/:id', urlCheck,(req, res)=>{
  let urlCollection = database.collection('urls');
  urlCollection.insertOne(req.urlObject)
  .then((docs)=>{
    res.send(req.urlObject);
  })
  .catch((e)=>{
    res.status(404).send("Unexpected Error")
  });
});
```

I have made a route in my express app:
'/new/:id'.
In this route I have to pass an url with protocol as a parameter.When i pass a url like 'www.amazon.com' than everything works according to my code.But when I pass 'http://www.amazon.com' than my browser shows
Cannot GET /new/http://www.amazon.com .

Comment: Can you post some code stuff so that someone can help you?

Comment: app.get('/new/:id', urlCheck,(req, res)=>{
  let urlCollection = database.collection('urls');
  urlCollection.insertOne(req.urlObject)
  .then((docs)=>{
    res.send(req.urlObject);
    // database.close();
  })
  .catch((e)=>{
    // database.close();
    res.status(404).send("Unexpected Error")
  });
});